# Spring - Are annotations like @Component BeanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring

I read that Spring annotations like @Autowired, @Transactional & @PostConstruct are a form of / use BeanPostProcessors. So from what I understand about BeanPostProcessors, they are used to manage the lifecycle of a Spring Bean. Meaning you can specify any code which should be run before or after the intialization of a bean.

Now annotations like @Component or @Bean specify to Spring that it should create beans of this type. For example,

```
@Component
public Class Foo {

}
```

will tell spring to create a Bean of type "Foo" and then Spring will manage it's lifecycle. So does that make @Component and @Bean BeanPostProcessors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that Spring annotations like `@Autowired`, `@Transactional` & `@PostConstruct` are a form of / use BeanPostProcessors.

Neither, it's actually the opposite. It is BeanPostProcessors that look for the annotations and react accordingly.

- [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) - `BeanPostProcessor` implementation that autowires annotated fields, setter methods, and arbitrary config methods. Such members to be injected are detected through annotations: by default, Spring's [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) and [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotations.

  Also supports JSR-330's [`@Inject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html?is-external=true) annotation, if available, as a direct alternative to Spring's own `@Autowired`.
- [`CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) - `BeanPostProcessor` implementation that supports common Java annotations out of the box, in particular the JSR-250 annotations in the [`javax.annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/package-summary.html) package. These common Java annotations are supported in many Java EE 5 technologies (e.g. JSF 1.2), as well as in Java 6's JAX-WS.

  This post-processor includes support for the [`PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html?is-external=true) and [`PreDestroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html?is-external=true) annotations - as init annotation and destroy annotation, respectively - through inheriting from `InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` with pre-configured annotation types.

Note that [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) is not handled by a `BeanPostProcessor`.

---

> Now annotations like `@Component` or `@Bean` specify to Spring that it should create beans of this type. [...] So does that make `@Component` and `@Bean` BeanPostProcessors?

No.

[`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) is an annotation that the component-scanning framework looks for to find beans to register. The component-scanning framework also looks for annotations that are themselves annotated with `@Component`, such as the [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), [`@Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html), [`@Service`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html), and [`@Repositiory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) annotations.

The [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation is then handled by a [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) (not a [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html)).

- [`ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html) - `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` used for bootstrapping processing of `@Configuration` classes.

  This post processor is priority-ordered as it is important that any `Bean` methods declared in `@Configuration` classes have their corresponding bean definitions registered before any other `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` executes.

Comment: Thanks @Andres for such a detailed answer. This clears my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

**No! They are different.**

1. `BeanPostProcessor` is used to perform some operations before and after creating a bean,this allows us to add some code before and after creating the bean.

BeanPostProcessor class has two methods.

- `postProcessBeforeInitialization` : It's used to make sure required actions are taken before initialization. e.g. you want to load certain property file/read data from the remote source/service.
- `postProcessAfterInitialization` : It takes care of tasks that you want to do after initialization before bean reference is given to application.

Refer to : [spring-doc-beans-customizing-using-BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp)
 interface for details.

---

2. `@Component` : It's the most generic Spring annotation.

A Java class decorated with `@Component` is found during classpath scanning and registered in the context as a Spring bean.

Refer to :  [spring-doc-component-annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) for details.

Comment: This. Basically the `@Component` and `@Bean` annotations are used as targets so that Spring can find all of the objects it should instantiate on startup. You can do something similar yourself with a custom annotation and reflection, if you want to "try it out" yourself.